# John The Ripper 'No password hashes loaded'(see FAQ)

Tags: passwords, password-hash

I am trying to learn John. I've been through the FAQ and this tutorial, but am stuck.

I have made a RAR4 password hash. It's super simple. The password is 'test'. I now want to use a tool to crack it.

I've saved it to a file "test.txt".It has:

```
Red dead redemption.rar:$RAR3$*1*de613099dc859cfd*00000000*16*0*1*b52125c28c4fc60a1c00f313d0fb68ca*33:1::Red dead redemption.torrent
```

When running the following command, I get 'No password hashes loaded'

What should I do to get this working please?

```
Command: john.exe test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

$$ in your hash specify that they are encrypted with yescrypt, Hence you need to specify format to the john

```
john.exe --format=crypt test.txt
```

This should work